# Python 2.7 define a supporting function to calculate the average

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to define a supporting function `getMean(alist)` to calculate the average that will be printed out from another function `getStats(city_populations)`.

My code:

```
def getMean(alist):
    alist = sum(city_population,0.0)/len(city_population)


def getStats(city_populations):
    city_populations.sort(key=int)
    print "The population data in asecending order is:", city_populations
    city_populations.sort(reverse=True)
    print "The population data in descending order is:", city_populations
    print "The max value of the population data is", max(city_populations)
    print "The min value of the populatioon data is", min(city_populations)
    average = getMean(alist)
    print "The mean of the collected data is",average
```

Error:

> NameError: name 'alist' is not defined

How can I enable `getStats` to use the value from `getMean`?

Comment: If you have resolved your issue, please select an answer or delete your question

Comment: I am trying to accept your answer but I keep getting an error saying I can accept in a few mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# You passed in the wrong variable
average = getMean(city_population)

# The variable you passed is now called 'alist'
# And by returning the average, your function getStats now has access to it
def getmean(alist):
    return sum(alist,0.0)/len(alist)
```